# how to send audio file through http post to a server from ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have two function recordsound and post this recorded sound to the server.

this is the following code i used to post to the server

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recordedTmpFile" ofType:@"caf"];
 NSURL *file =[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
 NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile];
 NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

//nsdata to string

```
 NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[postData  bytes]];
```

//http post

```
NSMutableString *jsonRequest = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[jsonRequest appendString:newStr];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http address"];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)'s library. It has a setFile: method to allow you posting a file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to change the audio file data in binary format then send it in network by http protocol.

Then at server side you have to write a code to accept that binary file then convert it into proper audio file and store it on server.

This is how you can do your task...